# Accessing the SSL certificate on the server (private key)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, ssl

I want to decrypt a message that was encrypted on the client side by using my website's public key:

```
URL httpsURL = new URL("https://mediashuttle.com/");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) httpsURL.openConnection();
connection.connect();
Certificate cert = connection.getServerCertificates()[0];
PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
```

Now on the server (Tomcat) side I would like to decrypt the message which was passed into a Servlet. Can you tell me how to retrieve the private key inside Tomcat to decrypt a message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the key from the keystore where the server key is stored. Like this:

```
File keyStoreFile = new File("path/to/keystore/file.jks");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile);

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());
Key key = keyStore.getKey("yourKeyAlias", "changeit".toCharArray());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] encrypted = getEncripted();
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
```